# Animation on qwidget is not working

Tags: c++, qt

I want a widget to animate its opacity when it is shown/hidden. I used the below code, but it does not work.

If I animate the property "maximumHeight", it gets animated in show(), but not in hide(). Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Header file
*byeform.h*

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

namespace Ui {
class ByeForm;
}

class ByeForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ByeForm(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ByeForm();

private:
    Ui::ByeForm *ui;

    QPropertyAnimation *mpTransition;

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
};
```

Source file
 
*byeform.cpp*

```
#include "byeform.h"
#include "ui_byeform.h"
#include <QDebug>

ByeForm::ByeForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ByeForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->installEventFilter(this);

    mpTransition = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "windowOpacity");
    mpTransition->setDuration(1000);
    mpTransition->setStartValue(0.00);
    mpTransition->setEndValue(1.00);
}

ByeForm::~ByeForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool ByeForm::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (this == obj && QEvent::Show == event->type())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "in show";
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
        mpTransition->start();
    }
    else if (this == obj && (QEvent::Hide == event->type() ||
                             QEvent::Close == event->type()))
    {
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        mpTransition->start();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try `return true;` at end of esle if block.

Comment: call superclass in eventfilter? return QWidget::eventfilter(...); at the end, if you process the event, return true.

Comment: @timocov: return true; did not help

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix it?

```
bool ByeForm::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (this == obj && QEvent::Show == event->type())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "in show";
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
        mpTransition->start();
        return true; // you might want to remove this line
    }
    else if (this == obj && (QEvent::Hide == event->type() ||
                             QEvent::Close == event->type()))
    {
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        mpTransition->start();
        return true; // you might want to remove this line
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

---

Ofcourse, it doesn't work because it's already hidden when you start the animation. You need to prolong the visibility until your animation has finished.

Like this, maybe:

```
void ByeForm::setVisible(bool visible)
{
    if(isVisible() && !visible) // transition to hide
    {
        // m_bHideCalled = true;

        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        mpTransition->start();
        QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(hide());
    }
    if(!isVisible() && visible) // transition to show
    {
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
        mpTransition->start();
    show();
    }
//    if(m_bHideCalled)
//    {
//        m_bHideCalled = false;
//        hide();
//    }
}
```

Note that you MIGHT need the m_bHideCalled. Set it to false in the constructor. The name could be better though.

Comment: adding the above didn't show my application at all.. I have declared `void setVisible(bool visible);` in public section and defined as above...

Comment: I think the set visible is getting executed in loops, because show() or hide() will be internally calling setVisible() function only, right?

Comment: I fixed recursive call of setVisible() function by calling `QWidget::setVisible(false);` and `QWidget::setVisible(true);`... and find that the animation does not take place. The only change happened is that widget gets hidden after 1 second.

Comment: Well, i guess you are going to need this too. I don't know what might be wrong with the animation though. Does it work if you play it from some other place than close?

Comment: I just do show and hide of two widgets. `if (mpHelloForm->isVisible())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "hello visible";
        mpHelloForm->hide();
        mpByeForm->show();
    }` and the animation works for show if the animation property is `mpTransition = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "maximumHeight");`

Comment: Hmm, maybe the widget is already disabled in some way. What if you override the closeEvent method and play the animation from there? Do not call the QWidget::closeEvent method from it, wait 1 second to call it.

Comment: I do not close the widget, I only hide it. Also, I don't understand why it works for property 'maximumHeight' and not for 'windowOpacity' while show is called. :(

Answer (score 0):

It works, but I think that it not good way to do this (I think that you should be do animate before close event will coming)

```
bool ByeForm::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (this == obj && QEvent::Show == event->type())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "in show";
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
        mpTransition->start();
    }
    else if (this == obj && (QEvent::Hide == event->type() ||
                             QEvent::Close == event->type()))
    {
        mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
        mpTransition->start();

        while (mpTransition->state() == QAbstractAnimation::Running)
        {
            QApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Other method**

Also you can override closeEvent method like this:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* e)
{
    mpTransition->setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
    mpTransition->start();
    e->ignore();
}
```

but in this case you should do something after animate will finished (for example connect on signal `finished` and call some method for closing window/application/etc).
Also you should be check, would manually call close event or by user operations.

Comment: It is strange. Could you upload example which doesn't work (ui, cpp, h files)?